# How to remove (pop) initial layers of Keras InceptionV3 pre-trained model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am trying to use pre-trained InceptionV3 model. However, I want to remove initial five layers and add my custom layers. How can I do that? I tried `model.layers.pop(0)`, but that alone will not solve the problem.

Edit:

`tf.keras` does not help either as mentioned in the first answer:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`model.layers.pop()` doesn't work in the same way in `tf.keras` as it doesn in `Keras`. In `tf.keras`, `model.layers` is a view of the model. You can't remove the layers but what you can do is define the layer for which you want the output. For example,

```
base_model = InceptionV3(shape=shape, weights="imagenet", include_top=True)

# you don't want the last five layers:
base_model_output = base_model.layers[-6].output

# new layers
outputs = Dense(....)(base_model_output)
model = Model(base_model.input, outputs)
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. However, I am looking for removing `initial` five layers. I have custom Input and other layers.

Comment: This is equivalent to that only. You can choose any layer input as the input to your model and any layer output as output to your model

Comment: Thanks, but it did not help. Can you please check what wrong I am doing here? I just edited question details with the error. Your snippet of the code for `input` specifically will help here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since the first few layers starting from the input are changed, then the pretrained weights cannot be used. So, the architecture can be directly taken from here and modified accordingly instead of trying complex surgeries.

https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/inception_v3.py

Comment: Very true. But, that does not help in loading weights. There must be a way to use weights for all other layers and still not use initial `k` layers.

Comment: The weights of the subsequent layers may not be relevant because the outputs(feature maps) of the initial layers have changed completely. Even if this has to be done, iterating through the layers(model.layers) and getting/setting weights(layer.get_weights/layer.set_weights) is possible.